# Problem with multicolumn table

Tags: tables, align, multicolumn

What is the best way to get a table like this in LaTeX?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Asking for "the best way" to create a table is inherently subjective. Sort of like asking, "what's the best breakfast cereal?" Is there a reason you are asking for "the best way"? If so, how do you define "best"? Are you willing to receive suggestions for "a way" to create the table?

Comment: Should the "S   S   S" be the multicolumn you speak of? If it should be exactly over the lines between the columns, it might be something different. For that,  `tikz` could be a way.

Comment: What have you tried? This is not a "do it for me site". I like @Mico's comment.

Comment: I'm sorry for not elaborating my question further but English is not my main language and I don't know the exact English terminology for asking about this exactly the way I wanted it. I figured no sentences and explanations were better than ambiguous/poorly-worded ones.

I tried using bot ```spreadtable``` and ```multicolumn``` but none worked.

I define the "best" way as doing it as close to the illustration as possible, no matter the code or the methods used. Again, I apologise for the short answer and for making it seem like I didn't try. I searched all over and couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `{NiceArray}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$\begin{NiceArray}{c|c|c|c}
\Block{1-2}{\scriptstyle S}& \Block{1-2}{\scriptstyle S} & \Block{1-2}{\scriptstyle S} & \\
\hline
1 & 2 & \hphantom{1} & 1 \\
\hline
2 &   & &   \\
\hline
\end{NiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the first code]

If your columns have not the same width, you can put the `S` above the vertical rules by using Tikz (and the PGF/Tikz nodes created by `nicematrix`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

$\begin{NiceArray}{c|c|c|c}
  \hline
  1 & 2 & 123478 & 1 \\
  \hline
  2 &   & &   \\
  \hline
\CodeAfter
  \tikz \foreach \i in {2,3,4} \node at (1-|\i) [above] { $\scriptstyle S$ } ; 
\end{NiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: It looks to my eyes as if the numbers are not centred vertically. They seem slightly too high.

Comment: @Smid. The numbers are at the same position as they are in the standard environment `{array}`  (in fact `{NiceArray}` uses an `{array}`). In that environment, a *line of text* is centered. That means a text such as `an example of text` will be centered and you see that you need space below the baseline for the letter `p`. However, there are tools to change the vertical position (such as `\extrarowheight`)...

Answer (score 8):

With `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}
\newlength{\mylen}
\settowidth{\mylen}{2}
\newsavebox{\mysep}
\sbox{\mysep}{\scriptsize\bfseries\textit{S}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{
        columns={wd=\mylen},
        cells={c,m},
        hline{2-Z}={leftpos=-1, rightpos=-1, endpos},
        vline{2-Y}={2-Z}{},
        vline{2-4}={1}{text=\clap{\usebox{\mysep}}},
        }
        &&&\\
        1&2&&1\\
        2&&&2\\
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is a hacky way using two tabulars.

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\hspace{0pt}\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{ C{1mm} *{3}{C{4mm}}}
    & S & S & S
\end{tabular}

\noindent
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{tabular}{ C{4mm} *{3}{|C{4mm}} }
    \hline
    1 & 2 &   & 1\\ \hline
    2 &   &   & 2\\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

#### Result

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In `tabular`-like environments, it is possible to insert texts as column separators via `@{}` between column types. On the other hand, `\multicolumn` can redefine a column-type in place for one cell. Hence, in your case you just need to add a chain of `\multicolumn{1}{c@{\clap{$S$}}}` macros in the first row--`\clap` creates zero width box, otherwise `S` would affect space between cells.

Just to make sure all cells have the same width, I define custom column types: `L`, `C` and `R`. But you may not necessarily need that.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.35cm}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.35cm}}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{0.35cm}}

\newcommand\mc{\multicolumn{1}{c@{\clap{$S$}}}{}}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{} L *2{|C} | R @{}}
    \mc & \mc & \mc & \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & & 1 \\
    \hline
    2 &   & & 2 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]